# Flex navigation hamburger pushing Flex content when expanded

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navigation, frontend

I have created a web page using flexbox and have included a responsive flex-navigation bar. However, when the hamburger is expanded it pushes the rest of the page down with it. I have tried positioning the .active class to absolute on the "display block" and z-index of 10000, but these do not help.I have also tried wrapping the nav inside the row flex container but that ruined the rest of the layout.

Have considered the the js fiddle found at this link:http://jsfiddle.net/hRKgV/ but it does not have a flex box layout and I am wondering if floats are true to the concept of flexbox as it also removes that element from the normal flow of the document?

Any suggestions would be greatful!

Here is the code for the index page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Flex</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial;
      background-color: #faf6bf;
    }
    
    .header {
      background-image: url("images/index.jpg");
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      background-color: #cccccc;
      height: 500px;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px purple;
    }
    
    .hero-text {
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      color: white;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
      }
      h3 {
        font-size: 26px;
      }
    }
    
    .navbar {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 18px;
      background-color: navy;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .main-nav {
      list-style-type: none;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .nav-links,
    .logo {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    }
    
    .main-nav li {
      text-align: center;
      margin: 15px auto;
      position:
    }
    
    .logo {
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 22px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
    
    .navbar-toggle {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 20px;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    
    .active {
      display: block;
    }
    
    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
      .navbar {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding-bottom: 0;
        height: 70px;
        align-items: center;
      }
      .main-nav {
        display: flex;
        margin-right: 30px;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-end;
      }
      .nav-links {
        margin-left: 40px;
      }
      .logo {
        margin-top: 0;
      }
      .navbar-toggle {
        display: none;
      }
      .logo:hover,
      .nav-links:hover {
        color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      }
    }
    
    .row {
      display: flex;
      margin-left: 80px;
      margin-right: 80px;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .fakeimg {
      background-color: #faf6bf;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .side {
      -webkit-flex: 20%;
      -ms-flex: 20%;
      flex: 20%;
      background-color: orange;
      color: white;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .side2 {
      -webkit-flex: 20%;
      -ms-flex: 20%;
      flex: 20%;
      background-color: orange;
      color: white;
      padding: 50px;
    }
    
    .main {
      flex: 60%;
      background-color: #fffcc7;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    .footer {
      background-color: brown;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
      .row {
        flex-direction: column;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>        </span>
    <a href="#" class="logo">logo</a>
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let mainNav = document.getElementById('js-menu');
    let navBarToggle = document.getElementById('js-navbar-toggle');
    navBarToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
      mainNav.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  </script>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="hero-text">
      <h1>I am Jane Doe</h1>
      <h3>And I'm a Photographer</h3>
      <button>Hire me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="side">
      <h2>About Me</h2>
      <h5>Photo of me:</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
      <h3>More Text</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</p>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
      <br>
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="side2">
      <h4>follow me on socila media:</h4><br />
      <ul>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    let mainNav = document.getElementById('js-menu');
    let navBarToggle = document.getElementById('js-navbar-toggle');
    navBarToggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
      mainNav.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  </script>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it something like this you're looking for:

```js
const nav = document.getElementById('navbar');

const navBarToggle = document.getElementById('js-navbar-toggle');

navBarToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  nav.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #faf6bf;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  background-image: url("images/index.jpg");
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  height: 500px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px purple;
}

.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  h3 {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: navy;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 250ms ease-in;
}

.main-nav {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-links,
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.main-nav li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 24px;
}

.active {
  height: 18rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 30px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
  .nav-links {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }
  .logo {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .logo:hover,
  .nav-links:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 80px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.fakeimg {
  background-color: #faf6bf;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.side {
  -webkit-flex: 20%;
  -ms-flex: 20%;
  flex: 20%;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.side2 {
  -webkit-flex: 20%;
  -ms-flex: 20%;
  flex: 20%;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px;
}

.main {
  flex: 60%;
  background-color: #fffcc7;
  padding: 20px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: brown;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>        </span>
    <a href="#" class="logo">logo</a>
    
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="header">
    <div class="hero-text">
      <h1>I am Jane Doe</h1>
      <h3>And I'm a Photographer</h3>
      <button>Hire me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="side">
      <h2>About Me</h2>
      <h5>Photo of me:</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
      <h3>More Text</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</p>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
      <br>
      <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
      <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
      <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
      <p>Some text..</p>
      <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="side2">
      <h4>follow me on socila media:</h4><br />
      <ul>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="footer">
    <h2>Footer</h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

I added a `position: absolute; z-index: 10;` to the `.navbar` class (probably a couple other minor changes too to get the snippet running correctly).

---

#### Edit

I also added in a transition effect. To do this, I changed how your toggle was working. Now, instead of changing the `display` attribute of `.main-nav` it just changes the height of the `.navbar`. The `.active` class is now applied to the `navbar` element.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thank you soooo much! code works amazing and is no longer moving the rest of the page down!!!I have been struggling with this all week! So clever. I will learn lots from this code:)
Transition wise altering the height seems to be very good solution to creating transitions on the block elements. I tried animation code to make the block "fade in" 
but this did not work-kinda like on this website:https://www.swanseaclinic.co.uk/ but I think there is some J query there or similar (havnt yet learnt it yet):)

Comment: In my opinion a transition outwards is better looking than a fade in like that site has, but I suppose the downside to this approach is the set height. I'm sure there's ways around it, it would just take some time to figure out what the best approach would be. Glad this helped you out though.